# Solution to Helmholtz Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following Helmholtz equation, with some specific conditions.

$$b(x,y,z) - \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial z^2}\bigg) = 0$$

Compared to the standard Helmholtz equation, the sign here is negative (which can be accomplished with setting a complex number $k = 1i$ in the standard Helmholtz equation).

The conditions I have are as follows:

\begin{align}
b(x,y,0) &= 0\\
b(x,y,z) &= b(y,x,z) = b(x,-y,z) = b(-x,y,z) = b(-x,-y,z) \\
b(x,y,z) &= -b(x,y,-z)\\
b(\pm \infty,\pm \infty,\pm \infty) &= 0%\\
\end{align}

Basically a non-explosive solution. I expect also $\large\frac{\partial b}{\partial z}$ to be negative close to origin. The solution according to wolfram is as follows (F = b, k = 1i, l and m doesn't need to be integers in my case):

[image]

The solution I am trying to get for $b(0,0,z)$ is supposed to look like (according to my design):

[image]

I am taking only a few terms from the infite summation in order to fit to experimental data. Unfortunately it looks impossible to reach to a solution that starts from 0, growing then decaying, unless I make a two piece solution-one for the growing part, one for the decaying part (with some non-smoothness at second derivatives at a few points).

I am puzzled that I cannot generate an easy damping solution. What am I missing here?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I agree with the migration (but I can't vote with the bounty in place).

Comment: I really don't think the problem posed in this question is solvable. The solutions to the modified Helmholtz equation you've set up are almost certainly subject to a version of the Maximum Principle that's even stronger than the standard one for solutions of Laplace's equation. They would need to have a singularity somewhere (at which point it wouldn't satisfy the equation) to be feasible.

Comment: This is a mathematics question, but if he is a physicist, getting an answer from a physicist would suit him much better. I know that when I ask a mathematician anything he lists theorems, proofs and whatnot...always generalized even though I'm asking for a specific input.    
Furthermore, would taking a Fourier transform and putting the right side to $\delta()$ lead anywhere? Finding a Green's function to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's no solution for the problem. Just consider the $z$ direction, for which separation of variables can give you an independent 1D boundary value problem. The $z$ part of the Helmholtz equation is

$$b_z(z)-b_z''(z)=0.$$

If you solve this equation, you'll get

$$b_z(z)=A\cosh(z)+B\sinh(z),$$

where the symmetry requested by $b(x,y,z) = -b(x,y,-z)$ implies $A=0$.

$\sinh$ is unbounded at infinities, which contradicts your boundary conditions, prescribing that the function vanishes at both infinities.

Comment: @CowboyTrader such piecewise solution won't satisfy the equation at $|z|=p$, unless you insert some Dirac deltas into the equation. It would be better if you motivated your problem and your attempts to artificially "break" the solution.

Comment: @CowboyTrader Whenever you can substitute a solution of the form $f(x,y,z)=a(x,y)b(z)$ into your differential equation problem and get an independent separated equation for $z$ (and initial/boundary conditions!) and a separate problem for the other variables, this solution is a valid solution. And then you should just check uniqueness theorems for your problem.